# Почему не отображаются панели?

Tags: java, swing

Главная панель - mainInputPanel:

```
empls = new ArrayList<>();

for(HashMap<String, String> employee : data) {

    empls.add(new PremCalcPanel(employee, overTariffRate, workingDays));
    mainInputPanel.add(empls.get(empls.size()-1));
}
```

Вставляем в неё кучу мелких панелей.
PremCalcPanel:

```
public PremCalcPanel(HashMap<String, String> hm, String overTariffRate, String workingDays) {
    super(new GridBagLayout());

    createComponents(hm, overTariffRate, workingDays);

    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 0, 0, Color.DARK_GRAY));

    setVisible(true);
}
```

Ну, создаём мелкую панель.
В итоге пока я не пошевелю мышкой всю форму, то эти мелкие панели не отображаются... что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Семён Семёныч!"

```
mainInputPanel.revalidate();
```

размер же панели изменяется.